# Is it allowed to create an object of the same class inside a function?

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP. I am just learning and I have to use it to find the actual/final URL of a link that redirects.

```
Class ABC {
    public function getWebPage($url, $redirectcallback = null){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061024 BonEcho/2.0");

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        list($httpheader) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $html, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $httpheader, $matches);
        $nurl = trim(array_pop($matches));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($nurl);
        if (isset($url_parsed)) {
            if($redirectcallback){ // callback
                 $redirectcallback($nurl, $url);
            }
            $html = $this->getWebPage($nurl, $redirectcallback);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

}
```

The above function inside class call the same function again and again to find the actual url. However I am already calling the class in some other file

```
$obj = new ABC;
$url = "http://www.anrdoezrs.net/asd/?ak=123";
$someurl = $obj->getWebPage($url);
```

But this does not work. Please suggest.

Comment: Put the return part **inside** function xyz

Comment: Sorry, that was inside the function, i edited it.

Comment: Well first of all, whats in $url and second, where does this magic variable $newurl come from?

Comment: let me put the actual function that i am working with.

Comment: First check that your function is getting called by putting echo statement at start of the function. If that works then check entire code and print $html.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class ABC {
   public function xyz($url){
      $html = $this->xyz($url);
      return $html;
     }
}
```

In another class call it with

```
$obj = new ABC;
$url = "Some value";
$someurl = $obj->xyz($url);
```

Comment: May i know the reason for downvote? i posted the comment when question was not edited.And this answer fits perfectly to previous question.

Comment: Not your fault. I have posted 3 valid questions and they downvoted me in all of them. They have lots of knowledge but can't solve a single problem. At least you have tried, that's why I upvote you and makeup your loss.